# Catch forced download using CURL PHP

Tags: php, facebook, api, curl, graph

So apparently Facebook recently (I think it is as of today) started to force download a profile picture when looking it up using the following url: `graph.facebook.com/{FBID}/picture?type=large`. Before it just showed it in the browser. This breaks some of the behavior of my app. I.e. all of the profile pictures are not loading anymore.

So I thought I might just run over the complete database; downloading all the pictures using PHP and uploading them to my server. But I don't understand how to do this. I do understand how to download and upload a 'normal' .jpg or .png file or whatever using Curl in PHP. But since this URL ends up downloading the picture (check it for yourself using a random FBID with the above mentioned URL) I do not know how to 'catch' it - so to say - and upload it to my server.

I know it would be also possible to just use the User Picture Graph. But since the database is quite large, a part of the access_tokens expired. So I would end up with just a part of al the profile pictures.

Also, has someone any idea why Facebook changed this behavior (and not announced it in advance). I could not find it anywhere. Thanks